# SQL computed columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am coding a website and the customers now want different roles (more roles than specified on the specifications). So now I have to show less to each of the users.

For example if someone is **Data entry** user he can also see private projects.

So in for my table PROJECTS I have an attribute called STATE where shows the state of the project.

If it is:

1. Pending for approval,
2. Archived,
3. Delete,
4. Public,
5. Private

In my code I have a lot of SQL queries `SELECT * FROM PROJECT LIKE 'smth'` or `SELECT * FROM PROJECT WHERE COUNTRY=smth` and a lot of other queries where projects need to be returned.

So what I want is a computed value on the table PROJECT where it will return true or false to each row of the table depending on the **USER currently logged in**.

So I can call `SELECT * FROM PROJECT LIKE 'smth' AND computed_attr = TRUE` to each of my queries.

The problem is that I only know SCALAR_FUNCTIONS on sql, where you only can have parameters used on the current table.

When a user is logged in, and a query must run, I want to have **as a parameter this USER_ROLE_ID** so the function can choose to show or not the current row of the table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM PROJECT 
LIKE 'smth' AND scalarFunction(USER_ROLE_ID) = TRUE
```

Comment: It sounds like you should use a view.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_view. Search your database vendor's documentation for specifics.

Comment: @AndreasLympouras . . . You should tag your question with the database you are using.  A table valued function might be a good solution to your problem.

Comment: I am using sql-server!

Comment: In some cases I have a really difficult query like this: `SELECT p.ID_PROJECT,p.title,c.COUNTRY_NAME,p.PROPOSAL_DATE_YEAR,p.CONSTRUCTION_DATE_YEAR,p.COMPLETION_DATE_YEAR FROM project p INNER JOIN COUNTRY c ON p.ID_COUNTRY=c.ID_COUNTRY INNER JOIN project_media pm on pm.ID_PROJECT=p.ID_PROJECT WHERE ID_MEDIA = @IDMedia`